# Ubuntu VirtualBox Start error

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I recently installed a Virtual Box and Ubuntu and I've tried starting it. However once it starts I encounter an error. It reads as follows:

```
VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your sytem. Your 64-bit
guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot.
```

I've tried disabling the acceleration under the sytstem tab in settings,  but it still gives this error. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: vt-x/amd-v is enabled in bios. What is your cpu?

Comment: HP Pavilion. 64 bit Windows operating system

Comment: cpu make and model?

Comment: HP Pavilion Desktop PC 570-p0xx

Comment: Processor, not computer.

Comment: Intel Core i5-7400 CPU @ 3 GHz

Comment: The cpu supports vt-x and vt-d. Check your bios settings.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll check it out.

Comment: Have you tried **enabling** it. Why are you trying to disable it?

Comment: Put all clarifications into the question, by editing it.